# My pytorch neural network cannot fit the data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I want to use pytorch to approximate some data that is changing over time. The data predicted by the neural network I wrote is not converging and matching the data efficiently, can someone check this?

after shuffle:

[image]

loss value:

[image]

training data:

[image]

my result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since both your input and target has a dimension of 1 and the relationship seems fairly smooth, it might be a good idea to use simpler models such as polynomial regression or gaussian regression instead of a complex neural network.

Secondly, it's hard to come to any concrete conclusions based on the information provided. If you could provide the training data and loss values, we could offer better help in identifying the root cause.

Though I don't see any problems with the way you formulated your code, there are a few things that may have caused this issue.

1. 50000 epochs is an unusually high number, given that your input space is limited and a large number of model parameters, it's very likely that your model has overfitted on training data. You can confirm this by also plotting the ground truth vs predictions using training data, if it has indeed overfitted your model should perform very well on your training data even if it fails on testing data.
2. You didn't shuffle your data at all, it's possible that the numerical range of your training data doesn't or barely overlap with that of the testing data. See if your model performs better after shuffling the entire dataset, and shuffling the training set after each epoch. You can do so with the `shuffle` function from `sklearn.utils`.
3. Since your data is zero centered, it might not be the best idea to use `relu` as your activation functions. This will be especially true if your inputs are mostly or exclusively positive. Again, impossible for me to tell without looking at them.

These are some possible causes to the problem, if you could provide more information I can probably provide a more comprehensive feedback.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I uploaded the loss value results, but my training set is too large (800 rows), maybe there is no way to upload it here, but I uploaded the visualization image of the training set.
Some of your ideas are correct. When I brought it into the training set, it performed well and fit well, but after switching to the test set, problems appeared. I will try your method.

Comment: If you take a look at your training data, it ranges from +1 to -0.75, and your testing data only contain data very close to 0. Without shuffling, the it's unlikely that the model will perform well on the testing set. Furthermore, it seems that you're trying to fit a time series. Generally it's not a good idea to use a simple neural network to for time series prediction. I'd recommend you try gaussian regression or polynomial regression, or if you insist on using neural networks, explore LSTMs: https://machinelearningmastery.com/lstm-for-time-series-prediction-in-pytorch/